# Why can't you increase the Windows command prompt window width by just using the mouse?

Tags: windows, command-line

Instead, I have to go to properties > layout > window size > width and enter it manually. If you can decrease the width with the mouse, I would think that you should be able to increase it similarly. I'm using Windows 7 if it matters.

Comment: you can use ColorConsole instead, it's free and portable ... and it is not plagued by such limitations :) http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=software/colorconsole

Comment: Nice find.  Although, there's something about the looks of that program that gives me the willies. :)

Comment: @techie007 - i know what you mean, but it DOES have a bunch of useful features and advantages over Windows Command Prompt ... AND it's a gift horse :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't? :)

Aside from something to do with the buffering of a mono-spaced, text-mode interface, I'm thinking only the Microsoft programmers are the ones who know the reasons 'why'. :)

You may have (also) noticed that if you shrink the window width, it doesn't actually affect the text width, it just covers it.

I don't believe I've ever seen an OS with a dynamically word-wrapping terminal window, so I don't think it's just Windows. :)

Comment: osx terminal has this "dynamic word-wrapping" that you speak of..

Comment: Nice, but not very 'terminal window' of it, betcha an extended ASCII text interface would look awesome after being word-wrapped arbitrarily. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/en/Downloads.html) which supports <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> fullscreen and resizable by dragging borders.